# How to get data within specific period in the past

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have the task to pull the daily, weekly and monthly registered users. In my user table I have `created_at` column which contains the created date in INT format. e.g `created_at = 1679489745`. How can I get the list of users according to the specified period using the timestamp?

```
for daily user:
SELECT * FROM `users`
where `created_at` BETWEEN CURDATE()-1 AND CURDATE()

for weekly user:
SELECT * FROM `users`
where `created_at` BETWEEN CURDATE()-7 AND CURDATE()

for monthly user:
SELECT * FROM `users`
where `created_at` BETWEEN CURDATE()-30 AND CURDATE()
```

Also, I saw some suggestion that I should use DATEADD but when I use dateadd I get error saying `database.DATEADD does not exist`. I'm using MariaDB database. How can I achieve this?

Comment: try using interval function instead of dateDD

Comment: `SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())`

Comment: @Sanu Khan thanks for the response that answer did the trick , please add it as answer so i can accept it

Comment: great, i have moved my comment to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the comment to answers,

Instead of using dateDD use interval function since mariaDB not recognizing dateDD function

```
SELECT * FROM users` WHERE created_at BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())`
```